# firacode ligatures not working in iterm 2

Tags: vim, fonts, terminal, iterm2, ligature

I'm trying to use the firacode font in iTerm 2 on MacOS Catalina. I have "use ligatures" enabled, but only some of the ligatures actually work. In particular, the arrows configure correctly but greek letters and "www" do not. I have also tried the furacode font but to no avail. What can I try to fix this? If it is relevant, I am using vim as a text editor. 
Thank you.

Comment: Step one is probably to figure out what "use ligatures" means, because at the OpenType level, there's no such thing as just "ligatures", there are [_four_ types of ligatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/opentype-font-features#ligatures), which one(s) does iTerm2 try to turn on?

Comment: Oh gosh, I have no clue. It gives you checkbox options when controlling the font for "Use ligatures", "anti-aliased", and "use a different font for non-ASCII text". A friend of mine also uses firacode with iterm 2 and his ligatures work fine, which is why this puzzle is so frustrating.

Comment: Then it's probably time to both find out what iterm2 means with ligatures, and what's different between your setups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In iTerm2 Preferences > Advanced > Drawing (or just search for 'ligature'), change the *Improves drawing performance at the expense of disallowing alphanumeric characters to belong to ligatures* setting to *No*. This allows the "www" and "0xFF" ligatures to display correctly with Fira Code.

Answer (score 4):

Open iTerm2, go to Preferences > Profiles > Text > Select the "Fira code" font, mark "Use ligatures". Do the same to "Non-ASCII Font". Here you can see how to do https://ritesh-yadav.github.io/assets/images/setup-iterm-with-oh-my-zsh/select_font.gif